# Call to a member function connection() on null when writing a first feature test

Tags: laravel-10

I got a

> Call to a member function connection() on null

I write my first test below

```
class LocationTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $location = new Location();
        $location->name      = 'My Location';
        $location->city      = 'My City';
        $location->state     = 'My State';
        $location->country   = 'My Country';
        $location->latitude  = 123.456;
        $location->longitude = 789.012;

        $location->save();
    }

    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     */
    public function test_index(): void
    {
        $response = $this->get('/locations');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
        $content = $response->getContent();
        // $this->assertJson($response->getContent());
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

with env

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5433
DB_DATABASE=weather_app
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
    bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
    colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </source>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="pgsql"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="weather_app"/>
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

and database.php

```
'pgsql' => [
    'driver'         => 'pgsql',
    'url'            => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host'           => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port'           => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'database'       => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'       => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'       => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'        => 'utf8',
    'prefix'         => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'search_path'    => 'public',
    'sslmode'        => 'prefer',
],
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

After digging laravel docs I finally found that

```
 public function setUp(): void
    {
```

should call

```
parent::setUp()
```